# Hardware differences for ARKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, arkit

Are there any differences in what's available for ARKit depending on hardware? Is iPhone 8 a more potent AR platform than older models in terms of pure functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The face tracking features in ARKit (`ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`) require a front-facing TrueDepth camera. As yet there’s only one device with that — iPhone X — so the face tracking performance and feature set is the same on all devices that support it.

World tracking (with the back-facing camera) is available on any iOS device with an A9 processor or better. As of this writing that spans three years’ worth of iPhone and iPad hardware releases. Once you meet the bar for supporting ARKit (world / orientation tracking) at all, though, there are no feature set differences between devices.

Depending on what you do with an ARKit session — what technology you use to render overlay content and how complex such content is — you’ll probably find differences in performance across major device generations.

Comment: Thanks rickster. This is the kind of info I need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ARKit runs on the Apple A9, A10, and A11 processors. In device only it will work on an iPhone 6S or iPhone SE, or newer.

Comment: Thanks. But are there any differences in what's possible with ARKit on different platforms. Can I get access to ARKit functionality when running on an iPhone 8 that are unavailable in older models?

Comment: yes is possible to check  unavailable in older models

Comment: if (ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
} else {
}

Comment: I interpret what you are saying as ARKit as a whole is unavailable for older models (pre A9). But, providing you can leverage ARKit at all; are there any features in ARKit that requires a certain type of hardware or is the full API available on all ARKit-compatible models?

Comment: That developer forums thread is old/incorrect. For a brief time around WWDC Apple talked about having ARKit exist with a much-diminished feature set on A7/A8 devices, but a) they never actually worked in beta and b) Apple changed their message to say A9-only soon after WWDC.